# Sending Apex report based on condition

Tags: oracle-apex

please can you tell me if its possible to send Apex report to email based on condition if result set is not null?

Thank you

I made Static report in Apex and i dont know how to schedule sending of email based on condition in Apex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make this an Interactive Report and turn on the property for Subscribe, then any user can create an email subscription to the report which offers an option to skip if there are no results. The subscription can be set to some periodicity like daily.

There is then a management tool for developers to delete subscriptions as well as an API to do do things like change the email address used.

Outside or pure APEX you can create an export of a query and send it in emails using APEX provide APIs and then set this on a schedule using the Automations feuture or the native database job scheduler.